# Apache Solr Faceted Filters Customization

Tags: drupal, solr, faceted-search

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UOPbQ.png)

Need a solution to restrict the taxonomy terms visible on the faceted filters. Now it displays All the Parent and child terms associated with the product. Is there a way control which child terms to be displayed and hide the parent term. Refer: http://screencast.com/t/oZeHE1eiH

I used configure facet filter but it didn't help my cause

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://www.drupal.org/project/facetapi_bonus module
and exclude specific items from the Facet.

You can do this by going to your Facets and select Configure filter and type the terms you want to be excluded(comma separated list)

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Seems like the OP is already using facetapi bonus but that didn't help because exclude items in facetapi bonus excludes the item along with children. OP wants to remove only the mentioned items not the child